# ActionColumn Yii2, $key always return 0 based from searchModel

Tags: php, yii2

Basically, I want to make a CRUD page which is the dataProvider that came from Query class.

So, In controller :

```
 public function actionIndex(){
    $searchModel = new RequestBisaApproveSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Then in `RequestBisaApproveSearch();` which is the dataProvider :

```
 public function search($params)
{
    $karyawan = Karyawan::findOne(['id' => \Yii::$app->user->identity->karyawan_id]);
    $dataKaryawan = $karyawan->linkKaryawanPerusahaanBranchDepartementJabatans;

    $branches = [];
    $perusahaans = [];
    $departements = [];
    $jabatans = [];

    foreach ($dataKaryawan as $data) :
        array_push($branches, $data['branch_id']);
        array_push($perusahaans, $data['perusahaan_id']);
        array_push($departements, $data['departement_id']);
        array_push($jabatans, $data['jabatan_id']);
    endforeach;

    $query = (new Query())
        ->select("re.id as id, kar.first_name, kar.last_name, re.status, re.header, re.tanggal_permintaan")
        ->from('ytresnamuda_it.request re')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'ytresnamuda_hrd.karyawan kar', 're.karyawan_id = kar.id')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'ytresnamuda_hrd.link_karyawan_perusahaan_branch_departement_jabatan li', 'kar.id = li.karyawan_id');

    $query->where(['IN','li.branch_id', $branches]);
    $query->andWhere(['IN','li.perusahaan_id', $perusahaans]);
    $query->andWhere(['IN','li.departement_id', $departements]);
    $query->andWhere(['<','li.jabatan_id', max($jabatans)]);
    $query->andWhere(['!=','li.karyawan_id', $karyawan->id  ]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

return $dataProvider;
```

The problem is, when to make a actionColumn.
Yii2 have a function to createUrl in actionColumn like this:

```
 [
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
    'dropdown' => false,
    'width' => '150px',
    'template' => '{approve} {print-request}',
    'vAlign' => 'top',
    'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
        return Url::to([$action, 'id' => $key]);
    },
    'buttons' => [
        'approve' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
            return Html::a( $key, Url::to(['request-bisa-approve/approve', 'id' => $key]),
                [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-gii-action-customized fa fa-thumbs-o-up',
                    'role' => 'modal-remote',
                    'data-toogle' => 'tooltip',
                    'title' => 'Reminder IT'
                ]);
        },
    ],
],
```

If you can see in :

```
 'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
        return Url::to([$action, 'id' => $key]);
 },
```

id is $key.So, I check it with another column,

```
[
    'class' => '\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
    'width' => '30px',
    'attribute' => 'id',
    'vAlign' => 'top',
],
```

The result is : `id` is valid integer. But $key always 0.
Weird, but if someone have clue, it so much appreciate.

Comment: You don't need `urlCreator` when you are not using `$url` in `buttons` closure.

Comment: you can just use `$model->id` instead of the `$key` arg, i do suspect however that your table definition doesn't have a primary key. `show indexes from request`

Comment: the $key can be a composite so this value is not the id but a struct that contain the id  .. try var_dump($key) for inspect the content  .. and the struct

Comment: using `$model->id` instead of `$key' caused error. @csminb

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When performing a query builder, `$key` always returns from 0 in search result.

Then, I worked around it with the query from `ActiveRecord` to semi query builder like this one:

```
$query = tresnamuda_it.request::find()
        ->select("re.id as id, kar.first_name, kar.last_name, re.status, re.header, re.tanggal_permintaan")
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'ytresnamuda_hrd.karyawan kar', 're.karyawan_id = kar.id')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'ytresnamuda_hrd.link_karyawan_perusahaan_branch_departement_jabatan li', 'kar.id = li.karyawan_id');

    $query->where(['IN','li.branch_id', $branches]);
    $query->andWhere(['IN','li.perusahaan_id', $perusahaans]);
    $query->andWhere(['IN','li.departement_id', $departements]);
    $query->andWhere(['<','li.jabatan_id', max($jabatans)]);
    $query->andWhere(['!=','li.karyawan_id', $karyawan->id  ]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
```